# Duplicação do código HTML gerado

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Precetor - Perfil do aluno</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <form method=post action='' name='artigoform'>
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0" class="perfil">
    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM 
                    Inscricao, Aluno, EncarregadoDeEducacao, Musica_Aluno, OutrasAtividades_Aluno, Explicacoes_Aluno, Psicologia_Aluno, SalaDeEstudo_Aluno  
                WHERE               
                    Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND 
                    EncarregadoDeEducacao.ee_id = Inscricao.ee_id AND 
                    Musica_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                    OutrasAtividades_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND
                    Explicacoes_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                    Psicologia_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                    SalaDeEstudo_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                    Inscricao.al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];

            $result = mysql_query($sql); // executa a consulta
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)!= 0){ // encontrou o registo
                while($registo = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $lista .= "<tr>";
                    $coluna = "<td class='cabecalho' ";
                    /*Dados do aluno*/
                    $lista .= $coluna." align='right' width='60'><br><img src='imagens/aluno/".$registo["al_img"].".jpg' width='115' heigth='115' border='0'></td>";
                    $lista .= $coluna." align='left'><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$registo["al_nome"]."</td>";
                    $lista .= "</tr>";
                    $lista .= "<div align='left' class='perfildadosal'>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Idade:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_idade"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Data de Nascimento:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_data"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Morada:&nbsp;</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_morada"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Nome do Pai:&nbsp;</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_nomepai"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Nome da Mãe:&nbsp;</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_nomemae"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Nome do Estabelecimento de Ensino:&nbsp;</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_nomeensino"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Local do Estabelecimento de Ensino:&nbsp;</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["al_localensino"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "</div>";
                    /*Dados do Encarregado de Educação*/
                    $lista .= "<br>";
                    $lista .= "<div class='divee'>Encarregado de Educação</div>";
                    $lista .= "<div align='left' class='perfildadosee'>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Nome:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_nome"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Parentesco:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_parentesco"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Local de trabalho:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_localtrab"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Telemóvel:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_telemovel"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Telefone:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_telefone"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Contacto em caso de urgência:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_urgencia"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<h7>Email:</h7>&nbsp;<h8>".$registo["ee_email"]."</h8>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "</div>";
                    /*Serviços Educativos Pretendidos*/
                    $lista .= "<div class='divsep'>Serviços Educativos Pretendidos</div>";
                    $lista .= "<div align='left' class='perfildadossep'>";
                    /*Transporte*/
                    $lista .= "<div class='divt'>Transporte</div>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<textarea class='checkbox' maxlength='250' rows='6' cols='50' readonly>".$registo["tra_desc"]."</textarea>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br><br>";
                    /*Observacoes*/
                    $lista .= "<div class='divobs'>Observações</div>";
                    $lista .= "<br><br>";
                    $lista .= "<textarea class='checkbox' maxlength='250' rows='6' cols='50' readonly>".$registo["obs_desc"]."</textarea>";
                    $linha +=1;
                }
                echo $lista;
            } else {
                // não encontrou o registo
            }
    ?>
    </table> 
    </form>         
</body>
</html>
```

Quando abre isto numa página aparece assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que aparece tudo duplicado?

Answer (score 0):

Se conter mais de uma ocorrência na `while,` ela vai se repetir duas vezes, fazendo com que seja mostrado duas vezes seu código HTML.
Você pode usar o `SELECT DISTINCT` com o `GROUP BY` para selecionar somente uma ocorrência de cada.

Eu sempre aconselho o uso do PDO, ficaria mais legível seu código e ficaria mais fácil diagnostica-lo.